# urllib urlopen [WinError 10061]

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

encountered error below: 
[WinError 10061]No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 
    confirmed service is already started and no problem on service side. 
and no error show up if I directly run code as below:

```
Class Test(testContainer):
    restcall = "http://localhost:8086/service/records/all"
    def__int__(self):
        #service is started in init, 
     ...
     def restCallTest(self):
         getRecordsUrl = "http://localhost:8086/service/records/all"
         try:
            allRecordsResponse = urlopen(getRecordsUrl)
         except URLError as e:
             print(e.reason)
         return allRecordsResponse

      def test(self):
          response = urlopen(self.restCall)
```

but if I run as below by calling restCallTest in Test, will have the WinError 10061

```
Class Test(testContainer):
    restcall = "http://localhost:8086/service/records/all"
    def__int__(self):
        #service is started in init, 
     ...
     def restCallTest(self):
         getRecordsUrl = "http://localhost:8086/service/records/all"
         try:
            allRecordsResponse = urlopen(getRecordsUrl)
         except URLError as e:
             print(e.reason)
         return allRecordsResponse

      def test(self):
          response = self.restCallTest()
```